# Not able to upgrade node version in linux ubuntu operating system

Tags: node.js

I have node version v14.21.2  in my linux system. I have applied following code for upgrading node version  in terminal but its still showing older version-
sudo apt-get install nodejs

I have previously node version  v14.21.2. after upgrading it still showing older version.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried checking whether or not there is a new version available in your package manager? It isn't uncommon for them to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

You're actually getting the default version of Node.js from Ubuntu's repository of software sources.

Given that we don't know your version of Ubuntu and therefore can't be sure what version of Node you have installed when you run the command.

So you can try to update the software source via the command:

```
sudo apt update
```

Or I would recommend using the NodeSource source repository

```
curl -sL (https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x) | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
```

This command allows you to specify the Node.js repository you want to install and add it to the Ubuntu repository, and install it via apt

Answer (score 0):

> Use `nvm` to properly upgrade node

If you have  v14.21.2 and want to install v16.15.0 then

```
nvm install v16.15.0
```

To delete old version global packages

```
nvm install new_version --reinstall-packages-from=old_vesion
```

If you don't have `nvm` then

```
npm i -g nvm
```

1. To install latest version `nvm install node` or LTS by `nvm install lts`
2. To switch default version globally `nvm alias default x.y.z`
3. To use particular version `nvm use version`
4. To delete `nvm uninstall verison`

Comment: I have use command nvm install v16.15.0 and then node -v -->it showing version v16.15.0 on the terminal but when i reopen the temonal and use command node -v , it's again showing version v14.21.2.

Comment: use `nvm alias default v16.15.0` this will set the global node version, close the terminal then open new terminal run `node -v`

Comment: Is this worked in your case?